# Counting lines / max character in line with scanner

Tags: java

I'm trying to read in characters from a txt-file using a scanner, then I want to create a 2D-array where I want to put all the characters, including blank space.

My text file is looking like this (I've just created it to have something to try with)

```
###  ###
##
###   ####
```

My code is currently looking like this:

```
public class Sokoban7 {
    File file;
    Scanner sc;
    Scanner bc;
    String d;
    static int lines;
    static int lineLength;
    static int maxChar;
    int b;
    String[][] array;
    String line2;
    int r;
    int q;
    int m;
    int n;

    public Sokoban7() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        file = new File("C:/Users/joaki/Desktop/sokoban/readin.txt");
        sc = new Scanner(file);
        sc.useDelimiter("s*");
        sc.reset();
        Character c = sc.next().charAt(0);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            list.add(c);
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            lines++;
            if (line.length() > maxChar) {
                maxChar = line.length();
            }
        }

        sc.close();
        array = new String[maxChar][lines];
        bc = new Scanner(file);
        bc.reset();
        bc.useDelimiter("s*");

        while (bc.hasNext()) {
            d = bc.next();

            for (int n = 0; n < lines; n++) {
                line2 = "";

                for (int m = 0; m < maxChar; m++) {
                    array[m][n] = d;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
        bc.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Sokoban7 g = new Sokoban7();
    }
}
```

I need some piece of advice, is it really neccessary or me to make all this code, or is there a faster way? I can't make it work both counting lines, characters and yet have a decent consumption of space, any ideas ?

Comment: First advise: use variable names that mean something. d, b, r, q, m, n. Mean all nothing. They *obscure* your program. That alone makes me stop reading. You wrote code that works for the compiler, but doesn't work for humans. Beyond that: this community is *not* a review place. You should ask specific questions, "somebody assess my code and give guidance" isn't in the scope of this community. From that point of view: please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Also: *never* ever put commented out code into your question. You want to give exactly that information that your readers need to help you. Commented out code ... helps nobody. It is nothing but waste. Instead: use a source code management system such as git. Regularly check in your code. And delete all unused stuff quickly, instead of carrying around.

Comment: Yep, you are correct, I could for sure have brought a better question, guess I got frustrated and decided to post what I had in hope for some sort of help, I think the question on the other hand is pretty specific, I'm not asking for a review of my own code, but instead a better way of implementing the requirements.

Comment: The problem is: asking other people to read frustrating code is not very likely to work out. And: if your code is *working*, then it rather belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com . That is the whole point: "here are requirements, here is code to do that" ... asks to review that code, and suggest improvements. And that is most likely off topic here.

Comment: There is allways another way to implement something. And it is difficult to say what is better.

Comment: I'm not claiming that the code is working, actually it's the quite opposite, it's not working, but sometimes you got that feeling that you are doing something in a quite complicated way, that's the kind of feeling I had now, therefore I decided to ask for help, I mostly brought my own code to show what I've been trying out myself.

Comment: And I put that link [mcve] in my very first comment. When your code is not working, then you should *clearly* include actual vs expected behaviour.

Comment: You know, people said that stackoverflow can be somewhat of a challenging forum to ask questions, especially if you are new to it, I guess I've had a lot of luck getting friendly people who are willing to help. And after a certain amount of questions, you expect people to get better at asking. Next time I bring a question I'll put in more work in it. 

I cant help watching your profile seeing the line:
"Besides that: my goal on Stackoverflow is to help other folks solving their problems." The irony that life sometimes brings.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do this is with a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). Using Java 8, you could do something like the following:

```
final char[][] lines;
try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    lines = reader.lines()
                  // convert each line into a char[]
                  .map(line -> line.toCharArray())
                  // collect the lines into a char[][]
                  .toArray(char[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try that out, I thought I wanted a scanner to be able to use hasNext() and whatnot

Comment: @A.Maine The beauty of BufferedReader is that it already has built in functionality to stream the lines of your input (broken up by `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`).